# Does a solution exist where $p,q$ are odd primes and $p^a - q^b = p^c - q^d$ where $a > c > 1$ and $b > d > 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, exponentiation, congruences

From my thinking so far, there is no solution.  Is this an open question or is the answer well known?

Here's my reasoning about this issue:

If a solution exists, then:

$$p^c(p^{a-c} - 1) = q^d(q^{b-d} - 1)$$

Since $p^c \mid (q^{b-d}-1)$ and $q^d \mid (p^{a-c}-1)$, it follows that:

$$q^{b-d} \equiv 1 \pmod {p^c}$$

and

$$p^{a-c} \equiv 1 \pmod {q^d}$$

Assuming that we want to minimize $b-d$ and $a-c$, using [Carmichael's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), it follows that:
$$b-d = \varphi(p^c) = (p-1)p^{c-1}$$
$$a-c = \varphi(q^d) = (q-1)q^{d-1}$$

Now, this looks preposterous to me:

$$p^c - q^d = p^{c+(q-1)q^{d-1}} - q^{d+(p-1)p^{c-1}}$$

where $c,d \ge 2$ and $p,q \ge 3$

If we assume a multiple of $\varphi(p^c)$ and $\varphi(q^d)$, it still looks wrong to me:

$$p^c - q^d = p^{c+u(q-1)q^{d-1}} - q^{d+v(p-1)p^{c-1}}$$

where $c,d \ge 2$ and $p,q \ge 3$ and $u,v \ge 1$

Is there a straight forward way to show this is an impossible equation where $p,q,c,d$ are all positive integers?  Is this a tougher problem than it seems?

Thanks very much,

-Larry

---

Edit: I added additional information to make it clearer why $b-d = \varphi(p^c)$  David is exactly right.  If a solution exists, it will be a multiple.

Comment: I don't follow how you got $b-d=\varphi(p^c)$.  I can see that $b-d$ must be a multiple of $\varphi(p^c)$, but why must they be equal?

Comment: if you switch to + signs, 32 + 4 = 27 + 9.  with minus signs, 32 - 8 = 27 - 3, i guess that's why you want exponents larger than 1.

Comment: I think the way to approach is would be:
$p^c(p^{a-c}-1)=q^d(q^{b-d}-1)$ factoring out $p-1$ and $q-1$ gives
$$p^c(p-1)\sum_{i=1}^{a-c-1} p^i=q^d(q-1)\sum_{j=1}^{b-d-1} q^j$$ $(p,q)=1$, and WLOG $p>q\Rightarrow (p,q-1)=1\Rightarrow p|\sum_{j=1}^{b-d-1} q^j$.

Comment: In fact, that bottom row can be about $p^c$ not $p$

Comment: Also, we have that $q|\sum p^i$, as long as $q^d>p-1$

Comment: @David, I will update the question to address your question.

Comment: @Will, I think that if we change *odd primes* to *primes* and we allow $c,d=1$, then we have:  $3^2 - 2^3 = 3-2$ and $2^4 - 3 = 2^8 - 3^5$  I am wondering if there is an argument to show that there are no solutions for where $p,q$ are odd and $c,d \ge 2$.

Comment: @Stella, thanks very much for your analysis.  It gets us farther.  :-)  Do you see a path to show that the result is impossible?

Comment: I made a typo - those sums should start at $i=0$. Still working on what to do next. We are at: $p>q,p^c|\sum_{i=0}^{b-d-1}q^i$ and, with the assumption that $q^d>p-1$, $q|\sum_{i=0}^{a-c-1}p^i$

Comment: Also, $p^c=1$ mod $q$, so we get $q|(\sum_{i=0}^a p^i-\sum_{i=a-c}p^i-p^{a-c-1})=(\sum_{i=0}^{a-c}p^i-p^{a-1})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that my question is addressed by Michael A. Bennett in his paper [On Some Exponential Equations of S.S. Pillai](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/paper19.pdf)

As I understand it, the answer may be yes.  Bennett shows that for $a^x - b^y = c$ where $a,b,c$ are nonzero integers with $a,b \ge 2$, then the equation has at most $2$ solutions in positive integers $x$ and $y$.